# Azure Portal SqlAzureExtension extension failed to load

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azureportal

I'm getting a very strange error for the last few days. When I try to open any SQL Azure database in Azure Portal I just get an error message in Notifications center:

```
Refresh the browser to try again.
SqlAzureExtension extension failed to load
```

There are also hundreds of errors in console saying similar:

```
Failed to initialize extension 'SqlAzureExtension'. ErrorState: Error while loading extension SqlAzureExtension: TooManyRefreshes. Error: {3}.
```

Anybody faced same problems?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is normal for my subscription, I am not facing the same issue.

[Azure Health](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) is not showing issues. [Azure Health History](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/) is not showing issues since May 3.

This should be a temporary issue. If you need to do some administrative tasks using Azure Portal, try using PowerShell as a workaround until the platform goes back to normal.

Comment: This should be a  comment, not an answer.